# How to aggregate by 1 week interval in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have a table with amount and timestamp columns, similar to `Trades` at https://demo.questdb.io. I want to aggregate the data to have 1 line per week with timestamp of Monday at 00:00 over some period time (say the year 2023), I tried a SAMPLE BY query like

```
select timestamp, sum(amount)
from trades
where timestamp in '2023'
sample by 7d
```

The result started from `2023-01-01T00:00:00.012980Z` so I went to docs and added `ALIGN TO CALENDAR`

```
select timestamp, sum(amount)
from trades
where timestamp in '2023'
sample by 7d ALIGN TO CALENDAR
```

The result started from `2022-12-29T00:00:00.000000Z` which is Thursday, not Monday. I tried to do `SAMPLE BY 1w` and `1week` but it was rejected as invalid syntax.

How can I write a query to aggregate the data by 1 week starting Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weekly sample by unit seems to be missing in QuestDB. The workaround can be to group by timestamp truncated to the beginning of the week

```
select date_trunc('week', timestamp) as timestamp, sum(amount)
from trades
where timestamp in '2023'
GROUP BY date_trunc('week', timestamp)
```

QuestDB can add group by automatically, so it also can be written as

```
select date_trunc('week', timestamp) as timestamp, sum(amount)
from trades
where timestamp in '2023'
```